# Shaking the div after it is reached by smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to shake the content of the div on the webpage as soon as it appears on the screen by smooth scrolling there. I have the following html code:

```
<script src="js/jquery.smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jrumble.1.3.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
   <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
   <li><a href="#three">Three</a><li>
   <li><a href="#four">Four</a></li>
</ul>

(...)

<article class="item" id="one">
   <div class="item__info">
     <h2>One</h2>
     <p>Some random text here</p>
   </div>
   <div class="item__img"> 
     <p>Some random image here</p>
   </div>             
</article>
```

and the part that I possibly messed up something, I mean Java script:

```
<script>
 $('#stands a').on('click', function(e) { 
  var el = $( e.target.getAttribute('href') );
  var elOffset = el.offset().top;
  var elHeight = el.height();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var offset;

  if (elHeight < windowHeight) {
    offset = elOffset - ((windowHeight / 2) - (elHeight / 2));
  }
  else {
    offset = elOffset;
  }

  $.smoothScroll({ speed: 700 }, offset,


        afterScroll: function() {
            el.jrumble({
                    x: 4,
                    y: 0,
                    rotation: 0
            });

        }
    });
  return false;
 });
</script>
```

I'm trying to use the jRumble script that I found [here](http://jackrugile.com/jrumble/). 
I would like to achieve an effect that after clicking one of the links from the menu, the whole page scrolls down to the selected div and it vibrates for 2-3 seconds. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were serveral syntax issues in your `smoothscrolling`-implementation.
And as in the docs of `jRumble` described you have to start your animation after initializing the plugin on your element.

```
 $.smoothScroll({
        speed: 700,
        offset: offset,
        afterScroll: function () {

            el.jrumble({ //initialize the pluging
                x: 4,
                y: 0,
                rotation: 0
            });

            el.trigger('startRumble'); //start animation
            var demoTimeout = setTimeout(function(){el.trigger('stopRumble');}, 1500); 
            //set Timeout for stopping the animation

        }
    });
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bog7roqh/)

Sidenotes:

- The scrolling can be done by the jQuery native function `animate`
- The [shake](https://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/) effect can also be found in the jQuery-UI